# Assigning image source for previous and next

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using wordpress(with advanced custom fields) to insert images from the database into my html. I have a person detail section where it has each person's information in a carousel (image, name, bio, etc). The previous and next buttons are supposed to have the photo and name of the previous and next person. I am not sure if there is a way to get this with advanced custom fields or wordpress so I am trying to do it with js/jquery.

I am hung up on assigning the prev/next .attr("src"). With the code below it consoles all values, and then assigns the last .attr("src") it finds (obviously). I am having trouble figuring out how to assign the source of the prev/next img.

[JSFiddle for clarity](http://jsfiddle.net/17zm365p/1/)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**JavaScript / JQuery**

```
var img_array = $(".detail-center img").map(function() {
    console.log( $(this).attr("src") );
    var img = $(this).attr("src");
    $('.detail-left img').attr('src', img);
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom field types in ACF v5: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-new-field-type/.

Add your code to display the field under `function render_field($field)`. You can generate the `<div>`s for each superhero choice, and adding classes `left`, `center` and `right` depending on the current value (obtained via `$field['value']`).

You can then use jQuery (you can just put the `<script>` in the same function) to generate the carousel behaviour of changing classes on `.click()`.

To save the data, you should have a hidden `<input type="hidden">` field that updates on `click()`, and can save your field.

Just a suggestion.